# MYSQL 'select count(distinct col)' the result is wrong?

Tags: mysql

### This is my table

```sql
CREATE TABLE `tabletest`     
( `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL ,     
`type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,     
`parent_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' ,    
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),     
KEY `idx_parent_id_type` (`parent_id`,`type`)     
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

data:

```
type   parent_id    
101    0    
101    4    
101    6    
101    7    
101    9
```

this is sql 1:

```
select count(DISTINCT parent_id) from tabletest where type = 101
```

the result 1:

```
3
```

this is sql 2:

```
select count(DISTINCT parent_id,type) from tabletest where type = 101
```

the result 2:

```
5
```

why?  because the key?

Comment: with the sample data i don't see any reason for query 1 to return 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a known MySQL bug, you could check it via other engines (spark sql or something). Try changing your MySQL version. See [this](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=70038)

Comment: No problem, I ran across the same issue so I know how frustrating it can become

Answer (score 2):

Well, I replicate your test with your code and dataset and my results is (under MariaDB5.5.52) :

```
select count(DISTINCT parent_id) from tabletest where type = 101;
```

->5

```
select count(DISTINCT parent_id,type) from tabletest where type = 101
```

->5

What is your version of MySQL ?

Comment: MySQL version is 5.6.12

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT DISTINCT(A.type),COUNT(*) AS CountNumber FROM tabletest AS A WHERE A.type=101 GROUP BY A.type
```

Comment: `dbo.` is a SQL Server thing, not MySQL.

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT(x) COUNT(*) FROM ...` is identical to `SELECT DISTINCT x, COUNT(*) FROM ...`.  That is, `DISTINCT` is not function-like.